# A novel in which the only dialogue is internal?

Tags: dialogue, narrative

I am mulling the idea of writing a novel in which the only dialogue is internal. Has anyone yet published such a novel?

I define "dialogue" here as *any kind of speech addressed by a fictional person to a fictional person*. This includes monologue insofar as a person who speaks to themselves, either out loud or internally, is still speaking to a person even if they are not addressing somebody else. In the sense that writing is a form of "speech", an epistolary novel comprising a collection of personal letters also contains dialogue. Excluded from the definition are first-person narrative when the addressee is the reader, because the reader is not fictional; and most stream of consciousness writing, unless it is sufficiently formally similar to literal speech to be considered "addressed".

On this definition, I am not aware of any novels that are completely free of dialogue. But are there some in which the only dialogue is internal? I would like to know so that I can study the authors' techniques and use them, perhaps adapted, in my own writing.

(The first and last sentences above were added following advice received by @Cloudchaser.)

Comment: @Cloudchaser. I have followed your advice and edited the question accordingly. If it is still off-topic, I will delete it. Regarding your second point, I make my definition of dialogue clear. There is little point in having a semantic discussion, and your definition has at least as much merit as mine. But note that "internal dialogue" is a much used term.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, ruffle. I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: *Pincher Martin*, perhaps, or *The Martian*? I haven't read the latter and don't remember the first well enough, but basically any novel with a protagonist alone somewhere (think of the movie *Cast Away*). Also, there is a German autobiography written by an autist (who, in real life didn't speak, so probably there was not dialogue in his autobiography, either). Maybe there is something like this in English, too.

Comment: I guess you're still receiving close votes because you don't really seem to be having a writing problem. I mean, you haven't tried writing your novel and found that something did not work. You just want a reading list. Maybe a better place to ask for this is https://www.reddit.com/r/booksuggestions/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/suggestmeabook/

Comment: Thanks. I will look for somewhere else to post it, if the background to why I am asking it makes it unsuitable for this company's website. It was considered unsuitable on Literature.SE too. While having no desire to make waves, I observe that very few questions here are asked by contributors who say they have tried something unsuccessfully.

Comment: Contrary to the button clicks by White Eagle, F1Krazy, Mark Baker, JP Chapleau, and Amadeus, this question patently obviously is in in a writing context. But you are the management here, even if unpaid, so I will delete it.

Comment: Writers do lots of things, for example they do accounting (when they have income), but that does not make questions about accounting on topic on a site about *writing*. You want book recommendations, and  reading is an important part of being a writer, but *reading* is not *writing*. We would answer questions on "how to read as a writer" or "what kind of books a writer should read", but we don't do book recommendations, because that's a bit too far removed from the actual process of writing. Also, the site rules are decided by the community. We don't all agree, but that's what they are.

Comment: "*Writers do lots of things, for example they do accounting (when they have income), but that does not make questions about accounting on topic on a site about writing.*" That is such an unhelpful comment. Writing dialogue in which the only dialogue is internal is a kind of *writing*. It's not like accounting, or going to the toilet, and many other things that writers do. But you belong to the (presumably unpaid) management here, so I will delete the question.

Comment: Or you can delete it for me. Thanks. I'll delete my account too.

Comment: ruffle, your question is *not* about internal dialogue! You did not, for example, ask: How can I write internal dialogue? You asked us to *recommmend books*. That is off topic, and it does not matter that you want to read those books as a writer. I have tried to explain this distinction three times now, and if you find yourself unable to comprehend it, then maybe it is indeed better if you look elsewhere for help with your writing. Good luck!

Comment: @Cloudchaser - First you make an off-the-wall analogy with a question about accounting. Now you say I have asked you and your associates to "recommend books", a phrase which you italicise, as if I need it emphasised to be able to notice or understand it. I did no such thing. I did not ask you to recommend anything. Having decided you don't want this question, you are now reaching without success to find arguments why. The real reason is probably simply that it is unlike questions you are familiar with. Please do not waste your time. Please just delete the question. There is no need to reply.

Comment: This is a private company's website and I don't mind if the company or its unpaid managers delete my question. In fact I want the question to be deleted. What I mind is being given specious reasons in "explanatory" tones as though I have not understood something.

Comment: Don't be so puerile. The first version of your question ended with a clear request for book recommendations: "I am not aware of any novels that are completely free of dialogue. But are there some in which the only dialogue is internal?"

Comment: And we are not "management". This is a community, and any member can vote to close or reopen a question. Those that have voted to close did so because in their opinion your question did not meet the site rules, which you can learn about if you take the [tour](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour) or look at the [help center](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help). Getting questions closed has happened to everyone on this site, myself included, and while it is irritating, it shows your maturity if you respect the rules that this community has given itself.

Comment: If we have misunderstood your intention and you are not asking for book recommendations, you are welcome to edit your question to make it more clear. Or you can ask another question.

Comment: Best if I just leave than I get drawn in. There's no good reason for someone to think it was asking for recommendations. Recommendation involves saying something is good.

Answer (score 1):

"The Old Man and the Sea" comes to mind as a novel where I don't recall any dialogue. Santiago talks to himself, talks to his hand, talks to the fish, etc., but that isn't really *di*alogue. Or, of you wish, it's internal dialogue.

How does it work? You've got one character, against the elements. Nobody to talk to, so all dialogue is internal.

While "The Old Man and the Sea" has layers of underlying meaning. I recall some short stories by Jack London about a man's struggle with the elements, which were more about the physical struggle for survival. There too, if the MC is alone, all dialogue would be internal.

So, **if the MC is alone all through the novel, and all conflict is not with other people, but with nature, all "dialogue" would by necessity be internal.** There might be other ways to achieve the goal you seek, but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: Many thanks for this, and I've upvoted. I'll have a look at *The Old Man and the Sea*. In its first fifth it contains a lot of dialogue between the old man and the boy, but I'll study how Hemingway handles the bulk of the text where the MC is alone as you say.

Comment: I'm wondering how to do this when the elements are social rather than physical. Not sure whether anyone's done that before.